# Security in Ajax Get Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have googled many times to find the best security for ajax get request, but didnt find anything.

Had anyone body implement any security in get ajax request in MVC3 like passing some randam number or guid in ajax header and check it in global.axcx with session or database.

Comment: There is no difference between an AJAX GET request and a normal GET request. For example: if a user is logged in and has an authentication cookie set, that cookie will also be sent with an AJAX request.

Comment: But what happend if my website is open.. no need to logged in.

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult for me to understand you. Please try to explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Means to say.. i want to implement it in my blogging website.. User is not required to logged in to see any blogs but logged in required when user want to write a blog.. so i want some security in ajax request so that i can stop all request that are not send by website.